# Using async await, but can't save returned data in variable

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await

I'm trying to save my a token in redux reducer.
console.log works just fine, code is running and the token shows up.

when I try to save the result in a variable - async code does not run, and variable remains undefined.

**this is my reducer code:**

```
import { generateCSRF } from '../components/System/CSRF';

const csrfReducer = async (state = null, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'CREATE_CSRF_TOKEN':
            return  (
                async () => {
                    state = await generateCSRF(); // I'm trying to save the returned token in state variable, unsuccesfully.
                }
            );
        default: 
            return (state);
    }
}

export default csrfReducer;
```

**here is my async function:**

```
import { config } from '../../config/global-config';

export const generateCSRF = async () => {
        let fetchGetResponse = await fetch(`${config.api_url}csrf`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            credentials: "include",
            mode: 'cors'
        });
        
        let parsedResponse = await fetchGetResponse.json();
        console.log(parsedResponse.csrfToken) // this line works.
        return parsedResponse.csrfToken;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You can't have an async reducer, that will generate side effects. What you are trying to do can be achieved with Redux-thunk or Redux-sagas.

Answer (score 0):

Redux reducer codes that **CAN NOT** have any side effects, see [Reducers Must Not Have Side Effects](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects), they must be pure functions.

Side-effect code, such as API calls, asynchronous code should be placed in action creator, in order to support asynchronous action creator, you need to use [redux-thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) middleware.

The complete workflow is:

1. Dispatch `createCsrfToken` thunk async action.
2. Make an API call to get the `csrfToken`
3. Dispatch `CREATE_CSRF_TOKEN` sync action
4. Handle `CREATE_CSRF_TOKEN` action in reducer
5. Get the updated state in `promise.then()` method.

E.g.

`csrfReducer.ts`:

```
const csrfReducer = (state = null, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_CSRF_TOKEN':
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default csrfReducer;
```

`actionCreator.ts`:

```
import { generateCSRF } from './api';

export function createCsrfToken() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const token = await generateCSRF();
    return dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_CSRF_TOKEN', payload: token });
  };
}
```

`api.ts`:

```
const config = {
  api_url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/',
};

export const generateCSRF = async () => {
  //   let fetchGetResponse = await fetch(`${config.api_url}csrf`, {
  //     method: 'GET',
  //     headers: {
  //       Accept: 'application/json',
  //       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  //     },
  //     credentials: 'include',
  //     mode: 'cors',
  //   });

  //   let parsedResponse = await fetchGetResponse.json();

  const parsedResponse = {
    csrfToken: 'mocked csrf token',
  };
  return parsedResponse.csrfToken;
};
```

`store.ts`:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import csrfReducer from './csrfReducer';

const store = createStore(csrfReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
export { store };
```

`main.ts`:

```
import { createCsrfToken } from './actionCreator';
import { store } from './store';

function main() {
  store.dispatch(createCsrfToken() as any).then(() => {
    console.log(store.getState());
  });
}

main();
```

Output:

```
mocked csrf token
```